# Determining whether string is a proper noun in text

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I'm trying to parse a text (http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0wD91r2i) and retrieve the words and the number of their occurrences. However, I must not include proper nouns within the final output. I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this task.

My attempt at this

```
public class TextAnalysis
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>(); //instantiate array list of object Word
        try
        {
            int lineCount = 0; 
            int wordCount = 0;
            int specialWord = 0;
            URL reader = new URL("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0wD91r2i");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(reader.openStream());
            while(in.hasNextLine()) //while to parse text
            {
                lineCount++;
                String textInfo[] = in.nextLine().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").split("\\s+"); //use regex to replace all punctuation with empty char and split words with white space chars in between
                wordCount += textInfo.length; 
                for(int i=0; i<textInfo.length; i++)
                {
                    if(textInfo[i].toLowerCase().matches("the|a|an|and|but|or|by|to|for|of|with|without|chapter|[0-9]+")) //if word matches any special word case, add count of special words then continue to next word
                    {
                        specialWord++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if(!textInfo[i].matches(".*\\w.*")) continue; //also if text matches white space then continue
                    boolean found = false;
                    for(Word word: words) //check whether word already exists in list -- if so add count
                    {
                        if(word.getWord().equals(textInfo[i]))
                        {
                            word.addOccurence(1);
                            word.addLine(lineCount);
                            found = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!found) //else add new entry
                    {
                        words.add(new Word(textInfo[i], lineCount, 1));
                    }
                }
            }
            //adds data from capital word to lowercase word ATTEMPT AT PROPER NOUNS HERE
            for(Word word: words)
            {
                for(int i=0; i<words.size(); i++)
                {
                    if(Character.isUpperCase(word.getWord().charAt(0)) && word.getWord().toLowerCase().equals(words.get(i).getWord()))
                    {
                        words.get(i).addOccurence(word.getOccurence());
                        words.get(i).addLine(word.getLine());
                    }
                }
            }

            Comparator<Word> occurenceComparator = new Comparator<Word>() //comparares list based on number of occurences
            {
                public int compare(Word n1, Word n2)
                {
                    if(n1.getOccurence() < n2.getOccurence()) return 1;
                    else if (n1.getOccurence() == n2.getOccurence()) return 0;
                    else return -1;
                }
            };
            Collections.sort(words);
            // Collections.sort(words, occurenceComparator);
            // ArrayList<Word> top_words = new ArrayList<Word>(words.subList(0,100));
            // Collections.sort(top_words);
            System.out.printf("%-15s%-15s%s\n", "Word", "Occurences", "Word Distribution Index");
            for(Word word: words)
            {
                word.setTotalLine(lineCount);
                System.out.println(word);
            }
            System.out.println(wordCount);
            System.out.printf("%s%.3f\n","The connecting word index is ",specialWord*100.0/wordCount);
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("WEB URL NOT FOUND");
        }
    }
}
```

formatting kind of off, not sure how to do it correctly.

Which determines if a word is capitalized and if there is a lower case version of the word, adds the data to the lower case word. However, this does not account for words where a lower case version never appears such as "Four" or "Now" in the text. How might I go about this without cross referencing a dictionary?

EDIT: I HAVE SOLVED THE PROBLEM MYSELF.

Thank you, however, to Wes for attempting to answer.

Comment: There is no way to do this other than to use some sort of a dictionary.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to tell if a word is a proper noun using only logic.

Comment: Well, I don't think I have to cover every single case, but I believe that words after punctuation(.!?) should be considered as generally non-proper nouns, though possible there may be some false-positives... I just require a solution that would work for the particular text file

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your algorithm is to assume any word that appears capitalized but does not appear uncapitalized is a proper noun.  So if that's the case, then you can use the following algorithm to get the proper nouns.

```
//Assume you have tokenized your whole file into a Collection called allWords.
HashSet<String> lowercaseWords = new HashSet<>();
HashMap<String,String> lowerToCap = new HashMap<>();
for(String word: allWords) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(word.charAt(0))){
        lowerToCap.put(word.toLowerCase(),word);
    }
    else {    
        lowercaseWords.add(word.toLowerCase);
    }
}

//remove all the words that we've found as capitalized, only proper nouns will be left
lowercaseWords.removeAll(lowerToCap.keySet());
for(String properNounLower:lowercaseWords) {
    System.out.println("Proper Noun: "+ lowerToCap.get(properNounLower));
}
```

Comment: You could also use a TreeMap with the String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER constructor argument, and that would eliminate that lowercase->capitalized map

Comment: I haven't yet learned HashSet or HashMap in class, so I'm not sure if I can utilize that. Also, I'm wondering if this will account for words that only appear capitalized, such as "Four" in the text file.

Comment: It should print only words that only appear capitalized.  so "Four" should appear.

Comment: but since Four is not a proper noun, I wouldn't want that right?

Comment: I think if you want to do semantic analysis like that, then you would have to use a dictionary, like the others mentioned above.  There's no way to determine if a word is a real proper noun with just textual analysis.   I had just assumed you were going for a "good enough" type algorithm.

Comment: well I was thinking that a word after punctuation generally will not be a proper noun, but then to check if that word has another capitalized version of it that is not after punctuation.

Comment: @AikoAs if you are doing this for an assignment, you probably should talk to your instructor first.  The answers that you get here are either going to be contrived or assume that you know things that you don't.  The way for you to properly learn the material is to do it yourself.  Furthermore, answers we give may 'skip' steps that your instructor is trying to get you to understand that will be needed for the next assignment or class.  I would urge you to read [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166/40980).

Comment: I agree, however, I believe that I have made a genuine attempt with my explanation to the understanding of the problem. To the one answer provided, I have stated that it is not the solution I am looking for, as it essentially is just a better algorithm than the one I have implemented in my code albeit accomplishing the same thing.